# Pass checkbox value to js upon clicking 'submit'

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of checkboxes queried from a database via a js function at id='checkboxes'. I'm trying to pass the checked value to a js function but the console returns an undefined endpoint (i.e. ..../undefined HTTP/1.1 200 --)

HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:getQuestionData(this.value)" method="post">
        <div id="checkboxes">
        </div>
        <input type='submit' value="Submit">
        </input>
  </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function getQuestionData(sampleValue) {

    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("solve").innerHTML = ""

    var endPointQuestionData = '/api/v1/questions/' + sampleValue
    Plotly.d3.json(endPointQuestionData, function(error, response) {

        if (error) return console.warn(error);

        appendInnerHTML(response)
    });
```

};

Why is the checked value not being passed to the getQuestionData function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code in the submit button:

```
onclick='return getQuestionData();
```

```js
function getQuestionData() {
    

    var question = document.getElementsByName("question")[0].checked;
    alert(question);
    

    var endPointQuestionData = '/api/v1/questions/' + question
    Plotly.d3.json(endPointQuestionData, function(error, response) {

        if (error) return console.warn(error);

        appendInnerHTML(response)
    });
};
```

```html
<form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="question" value = "Question"> Question<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="question" value = "Solve"> Solve<br>
            <input type='submit' value="Submit" onclick = "getQuestionData()">

      </form>
```

Comment: I tried that but now instead of one /undefined endpoint, the console returns three. Which makes sense since it's calling getQuestionData() three times. The last call with onclick = "getQuestionData(this.value)" returns a /Submit endpoint (because it's grabbing the value "Submit" I believe).

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. So instead of passing the value through the getQuestionData() function, you're just grabbing the value via getElementByID. I've tried this method but instead I used getElementByClassName since I have multiple checkboxes. The problem now is that I get a method error..

Comment: You have to properly set **var endPointQuestionData = '/api/v1/questions/' + question** line, which is out of scope as I don't know the server internal. And you can use **name** property, my code is example. You have to modify your code according to your need.

Comment: Thx. The solution I went with was to use getElementByClassName which returns all of the checkboxes. Then I ran a for loop to filter out the value that was checked.  Your guidance helped, thx again.

Comment: If you are happy with solutions, then you can accept / upvote the answer